# How can I easily create a dynamic 2D matrix of vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Given my code:

```
G=zeros(height,width); %zeros or whatever

for y = 1 : height
    for x = 1 : width
         magnitude = sqrt(Gx(y,x)^2 + Gy(y,x)^2);
         gradient_direction = atan(Gy(y,x)/Gx(y,x));
         G(y,x) = [magnitude gradient_direction];
    end
end
```

I keep getting this (if I don't use zeros()):

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

or this:

> Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton
>   subscripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `G(y,x,:) = [magnitude, gradient_direction];` you are attempting to assign two values to a spot reserved for a single value with indices `(y,x)`. One way to fix this is to use a 3 dimensional array G instead,

```
G=zeros(height,width,2);

for y = 1 : height
    for x = 1 : width
         magnitude = sqrt(Gx(y,x)^2 + Gy(y,x)^2);
         gradient_direction = atan(Gy(y,x)/Gx(y,x));
         G(y,x,:) = [magnitude, gradient_direction];
    end
end
```

Now at each point G(y,x) you can store both of the values and access them as for instance `G(1,2,1)` for `magnitude` at `(1,2)` position and `G(1,2,2)` for `gradient_direction`. This assumes `Gx` and `Gy` are both arrays with size height x width.

---

Important thing to note is that slices of G along the third dimension will also be 3D arrays, i.e. `mag_dir = G(3,2,:)` will have a size `[1 1 2]` and not `[1 2]`. This may cause errors in some applications, examples include trying to concatenate `mag_dir` with another vector (that does not have the extra dimension) and linear algebra operations.

To resolve this, use [reshape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html?searchHighlight=reshape&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) to explicitly change the dimensions to to target ones. For the vector here it would be `reshape(mag_dir, 1, 2)`. Same holds for 2D slices like `more_md = G(1,:,:)` - this will need for instance `more_md = reshape(more_md,2,5)`.

Comment: Cool :) one thing, when you're using the three dimensional arrays and slice through the third dimension like `x=A(3,2,:)` you don't get 1D and 2D arrays, you'll get arrays with sizes like [1,3,1] i.e. still 3D - not just [1,3]. To use these slices as 1D and 2D arrays you need to use `reshape`. I can add a quick example if you want.

Comment: Added. Many operations will actually work. I ran into problems when I was programing something in 3 spatial dimensions and was trying to visualize/process cross-sections of the data. I'll look at those codes tomorrow and maybe update if I find something useful.

Comment: @Trt Trt Why not remain it as two different 2D variables?

Comment: @Adiel don't know the exact reason here, but not rarely in scientific computing you want to keep some things together like this. Especially if they refer to properties of a single 2D object (image, space etc.).

Comment: Right, but seems that it cause him more headache than advantage. Anyway, I would store it as a struct with different fields

Comment: @Adiel - true, structure has many benefits. Really the only time when I used multidimensional arrays was when they were 3D space points or in a certain CFD method that has 9 velocity directions spanning from each node (lattice Boltzmann method). In that case having 9 2D matrices would be a headache. Also 2D + time, third becomes time.

Comment: I also use 3D or 4D matrices, but for space-time coordinates, not for different usages.

Comment: @Adiel, yes. Definitely more usages seem like more headache.

Answer (score 2):

While @atru answer works, I would want to suggest a vectorize way that faster and neater, if that will help. The operations here can easily converted to vectorized operations:

```
G=cat(3,hypot(Gy,Gx),atan(Gy./Gx));
```

Comment: This is a better solution. One could also consider using [`atan2`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html).